# Using ReportLab in Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to use ReportLab in a Lambda function and I am having some issues. I added a layer that has ReportLab and its dependencies and I am getting the error:

`"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': cannot import name '_imaging' from 'PIL' (/opt/python/PIL/__init__.py)",`

My Lambda function is running Python 3.10. Should I try an older version? Does anyone know a solution for this? I read something about using a Docker Container and then uploading that over a zip file.